# How to parse values from database

Tags: mysql

```
    EMAIL                EML_GRP   
  -------                 -----      

HELL0@GMAIL.COM            1,2,3

HAI@GAMIL.COM              1,4,5
```

This is the table structure. How do I parse the values in the EML_GRP field? I am using mySQL.

Comment: what do you mean by parse there?

Comment: Java language like (I assumed) in your previous question?

Answer (score 1):

Never store comma separated lists in database.
Read about normalization:
http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/intro-to-normalization.html
http://mysqldump.azundris.com/archives/20-Nermalisation.html
http://www.keithjbrown.co.uk/vworks/mysql/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming (1) you use Java language and (2) you already submitted a query and read the values from a ResultSet, then you might have two Strings per record

```
String email = "hello@gmail.com";  // just to demonstrate
String eml_grp = "1,2,3";
```

To get the numbers out of eml_grp, you can use the String.split method:

```
String[] numbers = eml_grp.split(",");
```